# digit / ToolTipDialog : Modify orientation for a fixed coordinate ToolTipdialog

Tags: dojo

There are two ways of opening a ToolTipDialog. One is by giving 'around' attribute which is a DOM node and other is by giving x and y coordinates. If we give 'around' attribute, we can also give 'orient' attribute to define the positioning of ToolTipDialog with respect to the DOM Node.

However, I have to open ToolTipDialog adjacent a certain gfx shape. Since this shape is not a Dom node I have to use x, y coordinate to position the ToolTipDialog. But in this case, I always get a default orientation (the pointer/notch) always points upwards.

Is there a way I can change the orientation by giving x, y coordinate such that I can ensure that ToolTipDialog now opens with the notch on its left side or on bottom side ? Also can I modify the point where this notch will be created ? It could be possible that ToolTipDialog is opened a bit shifted upwords and I may need the notch at the center of one of its side.

Finally, am I right in using the ToolTipDialog for my purpose, or should I use some alternative ?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using or a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue? What is the reason you opted for the TooltipDialog instead of the Tooltip?